# What is the role of the cookie middleware in SPA Template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, single-page-application, katana, owin-middleware

The VS 2013 SPA Template is configured with the cookie middleware, among other middlewares like the OAuth MW or ExternalCookie MW.

```
    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
    // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Since the WebApi will authorize the calls made from the client side through bearer tokens and the external cookie middleware is there to support external login providers, what role does the cookie middleware serve in this?

Answer (score 1):

It's there as a replacement for forms authentication. Before, a user would sign in with forms auth, then it would issue a cookie, and create a principal object that represents the user's identity. With OWIN, the cookie authentication middleware does the same task.

It will also handle things like logins/redirects (forbidden requests) as you can see with the above line of code:

```
LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
```

Comment: My question was specifically aimed at the role it plays in SPA, what exactly is it protecting there? Since it is a spa app I am really concerned about securing access to web api and that is handled by bearer tokens and oauth middleware, correct?

Comment: @Tom - well, you want user accounts in your SPA right? What if one user shouldn't have permissions to see a view? The API could reject them, but you may want them to not be able to see them at all.

Comment: right, although my access token is likely to expire before the auth cookie does, so I still have to explicitly handle the redirects to the login page in those situations. The cookie middleware (browser) will monitor the expiration of the auth cookie, which is different from the exp of the access token.